# Getting substring of a string in flutter that contain and emoji can cause a render failure

Tags: flutter, dart

As part of the app I am shortening a user-given string to 40 characters and appending ellipses at the end if the string is longer than 40 characters. The users are allowed/able to use emoji in their strings.

If a string that is cut off has an emoji at the 40-character mark it causes it to fail to render and renders as a "�".

Is there a way to reliably get a sub-string of a text but without running into this issue?

Current code:

```
if (useStr.length > 40) {
useStr = useStr.substring(0, 40) + "...";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [`package:characters`](https://pub.dev/packages/characters) and truncate strings based on [*graphemes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapheme) (human-perceived characters) and not on (UTF-16) code units.

```dart
import 'package:characters/characters.dart';

void main() {
  final originalString = '\u{1F336}\uFE0F' * 3; // ️️️
  const ellipsis = '\u2026';
  for (var i = 1; i < 4; i += 1) {
    var s = originalString;
    var characters = s.chararacters;
    if (characters.length > i) {
      s = '${characters.take(i)}$ellipsis';
    }
    print(s);
  }
}
```

which prints:

```
️…
️️…
️️️
```